# Corrupted HD recovery, non-PAE machine

Tags: grub2, partitioning, windows-xp

I was trying to fix a corrupt hard drive  I was given information on trying to recover the files on a failed drive by getting ubuntu and looking around.

My laptop is awaiting a new drive so I only have an old xp desktop and the newer versions of ubuntu won't work.  I had to install ubuntu 8.4.  I put the disk in, and originally ticked the try but not install option.  While looking around, I hit the install button and even though I cancelled the operation (once I realized that it wasn't a good idea) a partition was still created which I didn't find out until I turned the computer on this morning.  I got the "master boot record error - insert system disk press enter" message instead of the xp boot I expected.  I reinserted the ubuntu disk and saw the partition. I don't know how to get back to xp.

I've been reading the message boards and see grub used to access partitions (if I understood that correctly).  I downloaded it but don't have a clue where to go from here.

Comment: Please make your title informative, it should describe the issue you are facing, that way people know if they are interested in your question.

Comment: Please advise the make and model of your machine, by clicking on the grey _edit_ link above and to the left, and adding the data. Also, the 32-bit version you can directly download from  http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/12.04/release/xubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso of Xubuntu http://xubuntu.org will work on your older hardware and has an interface more like XP, plus the version 8.04 you first used can't be supported here since Ubuntu has changed so much since then...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this might help you - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.